# Spring web application - Migration from tomcat to wildfly

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, jboss, migration, wildfly

I have a spring web application that uses Tomcat.I am trying to migrate it to jBoss/Wildfly application server. When trying to deploy it, I get these errors:

> Cannot upload deployment: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./revomon-tracking-web-html" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./revomon-tracking-web-html: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'trackAlarmDao' defined in VFS resource [\"/content/revomon-tracking-web-html.war/WEB-INF/lib/revomon-tracking-orm-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/com/revomon/orm/core/tracking/dao/TrackAlarmDao.class\"]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in VFS resource [\"/content/revomon-tracking-web-html.war/WEB-INF/classes/context/application-context-repository.xml\"]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc/revomon_tracking -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.revomon_tracking; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in VFS resource [\"/content/revomon-tracking-web-html.war/WEB-INF/classes/context/application-context-repository.xml\"]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc/revomon_tracking -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.revomon_tracking Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc/revomon_tracking -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.revomon_tracking Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourcePosition': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc/tracking_position -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.tracking_position Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'trackAlarmDao' defined in VFS resource [\"/content/revomon-tracking-web-html.war/WEB-INF/lib/revomon-tracking-orm-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/com/revomon/orm/core/tracking/dao/TrackAlarmDao.class\"]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in VFS resource [\"/content/revomon-tracking-web-html.war/WEB-INF/classes/context/application-context-repository.xml\"]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc/revomon_tracking -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.revomon_tracking; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in VFS resource [\"/content/revomon-tracking-web-html.war/WEB-INF/classes/context/application-context-repository.xml\"]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc/revomon_tracking -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.revomon_tracking Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc/revomon_tracking -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.revomon_tracking Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourcePosition': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc/tracking_position -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.tracking_position Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in VFS resource [\"/content/revomon-tracking-web-html.war/WEB-INF/classes/context/application-context-repository.xml\"]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc/revomon_tracking -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.revomon_tracking Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc/revomon_tracking -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.revomon_tracking Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc/revomon_tracking -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.revomon_tracking"},"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./revomon-tracking-web-html"],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined}

Please any suggestions how to fix it?